# Math Overflow -- Handling Large Numbers

Tags: math

I am having a problem handling large numbers.

I need to calculate the log of a very large number.  The number is the product of a series of numbers.  For example: log(2x3x66x435x444) though my actual series are longer.

I am getting a math overflow because product grows very large, very quickly.

Are there special math libraries to handle huge numbers?  Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: As others have pointed out - you don't need big number support for what you are trying to do. But if you do want to use them, many modern(ish) languages have big numbers built in. Libraries exist for many others (C, C++ etc). What language are you using or thinking of using?

Comment: Look for the "slide rule" library...

Comment: thats why you need mathematics.. :P

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a neat mathematical solution to this problem.

Rather than obtaining the product of a series by multiplying each number, you can use their log values.  The noted principle is:

```
log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)
```

For the example series (2, 3, 66, 435, 444), the brute-force product is calculated as 2 * 3 * 66 * 435 * 44 = 76,483,440.

However, you can also obtain the product from the sum of the logs. For a series (n1, n2, n3, n4,...) the product of the series is:  10 ^ (log(n1) + log(n2) + log(n3) + log(n4)...)

```
log(2) = 0.30103
log(3) = 0.47712
log(66) = 1.8195
log(435) = 2.6384
log(444) = 2.6474
```

The sum of the values is roughly 7.8835.  The product of the series is 10 ^ 7.8835 (76,483,440).

Since you're looking for the log of the product of the series, just the sum of the individual log() values, 7.8835.  That's it.

Answer (score 19):

Um: log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)

Answer (score 3):

Use Python ;)

```
$python
Python 2.4.4 (#71, Oct 18 2006, 08:34:43) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.log(2*3*66*435*444)
18.15258480477539
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Java classes BigInteger and BigDecimal can help

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html